# jinja2 template not found and internal server error

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, jinja2

**Python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def hello():

    return render_template('testing.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My name is pk</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also how to enable jinja2 in pycharm community version. I am directly creating html file and .py file in the same project

Comment: Can you show us the full error, and how you've structured your files and directories?

Comment: make sure your 'testing.html' file is inside the templates folder. It's better if you could show your app structure.

Comment: @coralvanda i got the solution by using below mentioned strategies. Thanks, please keep answering my questions.

Comment: @thangtn yes there was some problem with the file structure, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flask file structure

```
|-app
|--templates // where your html files must be in
|--static // where your js and css files must be in
|--.py files
|--other packages
```

Also jinja2 is in your python environment, if you have already installed flask.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked there was some problem in file structure. Now working perfectly.

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved

Answer (score 5):

By default, Flask looks in the `templates` folder in the root level of your app.

> http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/
>
> template_folder – the folder that contains the templates that should
>   be used by the application. Defaults to 'templates' folder in the root
>   path of the application.

So you have some options,

1. rename `template` to `templates`
2. supply a `template_folder` param to have your `template` folder recognised by the flask app:

   ```
   app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
   ```

Flask expects the `templates` directory to be in the same folder as the module in which it is created;
You'll need to tell Flask to look elsewhere instead:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../pages/templates')
```

This works as the path is resolved relative to the current module path.

You cannot have per-module template directories, not without using [blueprints](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/blueprints/). A common pattern is to use subdirectories of the `templates` folder instead to partition your templates. You'd use `templates/pages/index.html`, loaded with `render_template('pages/index.html')`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me.

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved